# Create child nodes dynamically for a node in MVC.Sitemap

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am working on an MVC 4 application where I am showing a menu on masterpage using Mvc.sitemap. I have a node named say "Tasks" which will appear everytime among other nodes on menu. I need to create child nodes for this node based on values fetched from database. Depending on number of values the child nodes will be created and on clicking each child code a certain function will be performed.

Since I dont know how to generate child nodes according to values from database, I have hardcoded nodes as of now in Mvc.sitemap. Below is the code of how I have been doing it now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Tasks" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Task 1" controller="Home" action="Index" url="http://localhost:...."/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Task 2" controller="Home" action="Index" url="http://localhost:...."/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>  
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Admin" controller="Home" action="Admin"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Help" controller="Home" action="Help"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

As you can see in the above code I have hardcoded the child nodes and also specified the url property.

Please help on how to achieve this dynamically. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what [dynamic node providers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) are for.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Tasks" controller="Home" action="Index" key="TasksIndex">
    <!-- This is the task template node - this node won't be added to the SiteMap, 
    but will be used to define the defaults of the Dynamic Nodes -->
    <mvcSiteMapNode action="Index" dynamicNodeProvider="MyNamespace.TaskDynamicNodeProvider, MyAssembly" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>


namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class TaskDynamicNodeProvider 
        : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
    { 
        public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node) 
        {
            using (var db = new MyEntities())
            {
                // Create a node for each album 
                foreach (var task in db.Tasks) 
                { 
                    var dynamicNode = new DynamicNode(); 
                    dynamicNode.Title = task.Name; 
                    dynamicNode.ParentKey = "TasksIndex"; 
                    dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", task.Id);

                    // NOTE: Controller is automatically inherited in the XML from the 
                    // nearest parent node where it is set, and action is set in the 
                    // template node in this example. However, you can override the
                    // values here if you need to.

                    // dynamicNode.Controller = "Home";
                    // dynamicNode.Action = "Index";

                    yield return dynamicNode;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```